# Updated version 12.04 & now GRUB line command needed; tab shows many unknown possibilities

Tags: grub2

My desktop for both operating system is dead in the water until the right GRUB command is entered. Is this a commonplace situation after simply updating the system? Without a cure my only recourse is reinstalling Windows.......Thanks in advance for any rescue help!

Comment: We need a lot more information to be able to help you. Like what steps have you done to get to this point? What is the current problem? Have you got pictures/screenshots of the problem? What hardware do you have? What operating system do you have? Edit your question with the new info.

Answer (score 0):

try if

```
update-grub
```

is sufficient.

If not you need to tell a bit more.
what windows are you using ? windows 7 or windows 8 with newer uefi-bios ?

Comment: I've got Windows XP, 2GB Ram, P4 1.5, IntelD850GB Mobo and Nvidia GE Force FX5500 256MB 4/8X card. In reading the related comments to my right, I discovered my GRUB was damaged due to interruption of the updating process. I see nothing except a black screen with the GRUB waiting for a command. When I hit the tab key, I see a whole screen filled with command possibilities. I tried most of these commands & GRUB rejected all. It would seem there would be a standard GRUB repair line for this situation. Much thanks, Jack